# How to find a centroid of a quarter circle?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

> Find the centroid of the quarter circle $x^2+y^2 \le  10$, $y\ge |x|$ assuming the density $ {\displaystyle \delta }(x,y) = 1$. give your answer as point coordinates in the form (X,Y)

So I first convert to polar coordinates:

$$rsin(\theta)^2+rcos(\theta)^2=10$$

Then I know it's a quarter circle that's bounded by $y=|x|$

So $\theta = \frac{\pi}{4}$ to $\frac{3\pi}{4}$

So now I integrate:

$$\int _{\frac{\pi }{4}}^{\frac{3\pi }{4}}\int _0^{2.5}\:\:\:rsin\left(\theta \right)^2+rcos\left(\theta \right)^2drd\theta $$

But this is just one integral. How do I get two? What am I missing?

Thank you.

edit:

[image]

Comment: Please do not post unsearchable pictures of text or equations.  Instead use *MathJax*.  Also, why do you need that text entry box??

Comment: @DavidG.Stork my bad lemme fix it

Comment: Are you sure $x^2 + y^2 \leq 10$, and not $10^2$??

Comment: @DavidG.Stork yes, the problem says $10$ on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this in polar coordinates as the question asks, please consider the surface as a triangle with two sides as $r$ and the third side as $r \mathrm{d}\theta$.

Area of triangle, $dA = \frac{1}{2} r^2 \mathrm{d}\theta$. As we know, the centroid of the triangle will be at $\frac{2}{3}r$.

So,

$\overline{x} = \displaystyle \dfrac{2}{3A}\int_{\pi/4}^{3\pi/4} r\cos\theta \,  \mathrm{d}A = \dfrac{1}{3A}\int_{\pi/4}^{3\pi/4} r^3 \cos\theta \,  \mathrm{d} \theta$

$\overline{y} = \displaystyle \dfrac{2}{3A}\int_{\pi/4}^{3\pi/4} r\sin\theta \, \mathrm{d}A = \dfrac{1}{3A}\int_{\pi/4}^{3\pi/4} r^3 \sin\theta \,  \mathrm{d} \theta$

$A = \displaystyle \dfrac{1}{2}\int_{\pi/4}^{3\pi/4}r^2 \,\mathrm{d}\theta = \frac{\pi r^2}{4}$

So, $\overline {x} =\displaystyle  \frac{4r}{3\pi} [\sin \theta]_{\pi / 4}^{3 \pi / 4} = 0$ (which is obvious due to symmetry around $y$ axis).

$\overline {y} =\displaystyle  \frac{4r}{3\pi} [-\cos \theta]_{\pi / 4}^{3 \pi / 4} = \frac{4 \sqrt2 \, r}{3\pi} = \frac {8 \sqrt5}{3 \pi} \,$ (for $r = \sqrt {10}$).

Comment: thanks! this is less confuzi

Answer (score 2):

Clearly $\bar{x}$ coordinate is $0$ (by symmetry).  The $\bar{y}$ coordinate is:

$$\bar{y} =
\frac{ \int\limits_{y=0}^{\sqrt{5}} y \cdot 2 y\ dy + \int\limits_{\sqrt{5}}^{\sqrt{10}} y \cdot 2 \sqrt{10 - y^2}\ dy}{\pi 10/4} = \frac{8 \sqrt{5}}{3 \pi }$$

[image]

The total mass (in the denominator) is just the density times the area of a quarter circular disk of radius $\sqrt{10}$

Comment: thanks so much you're amazing!

Answer (score 0):

Another (related$ ^* $) method for locating the centroid of a region with constant density is to apply Pappus' (Second) Centroid Theorem, which states that the volume of a solid of revolution is equal to the area of the region revolved about the rotation axis times the circumference of the circle swept out by the centroid.

Revolving the quarter-circle of radius $ \ \sqrt{10} \ $ about one of its straight edges (radii) generates a hemisphere of that radius.  We then have

$$ \ V_{hemi} \ = \ \frac{2 \pi}{3} · ( \sqrt{10} )^3 \ \ = \ \ A_{qtr} \ · \ 2 \pi  \bar{x} \ \ = \ \ \frac{\pi}{4} · (\sqrt{10})^2 \ · \ 2 \pi \bar{x}  $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \ \bar{x} \ \ = \ \ \frac{4}{3 \pi} \ · \ \sqrt{10} \ \ . $$

With the "center" of the quarter-circle at the origin and the edges along the coordinate axes, the centroid is thus found to be at $ \ \left( \  \frac{4\sqrt{10}}{3 \pi}    \ , \  \frac{4\sqrt{10}}{3 \pi} \ \right) \  $ , by the symmetry of the region.

To connect this to the other answers given by **Math Lover** and **David G. Stork**, the distance of the centroid from the vertex of the quarter-circle is

$$ \frac{4}{3 \pi} \ · \ \sqrt{10} \ · \ \sqrt{2} \ \ = \ \   \frac{4\sqrt{20}}{3 \pi} \ \ = \ \   \frac{8 \sqrt{5}}{3 \pi} \ \ . $$

For the orientation of the quarter-circle indicated in the problem statement, the coordinates of the centroid are then $ \ \left( \  0   \ , \  \frac{8 \sqrt{5}}{3 \pi}  \ \right) \ \ . $

$$ \ $$

$^*$ This is a related method because Pappus' Centroid Theorems describe the results found from the moment integrals for centroids of surfaces and solids of revolution, used in the other answers.